# Materialize center vertically logo brand on navbar

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have the following piece of HTML code for the navbar. Using materialize framework

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="brand-logo valign-wrapper logo">
        <img src="{% static 'imgs/logo_transparent_bg.png' %}" width='40px'>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="brand-logo center hide-on-med-and-down">
        Heartist
    </a>
    <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.logo > img {
  position: relative;
  top:1.4vh;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;

}
```

Here is the preview : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNgtr.png

The problem is that it's not responsive. If I zoom or check on my phone, the logo was'nt vertically centered.

Any idea without using X breakpoints ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The css you've used is totally unnecessary. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Your code doesn't even include a nav element. I would use the code from materialize docs until you are familiar enough to freestyle. if you describe or show what you are trying to achieve, I'll build you codepen using materialize markup and conventions :)

Comment: You don't need to add your own CSS to materialize components because they work perfectly with responsive. You could try to delete your CSS and keep the HTML clean as on documentation here: https://materializecss.com/navbar.html